# How to connect React Front-end to Node Backend while deploying on cPanel Hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cpanel

I have created a ReactJs Front-end and NodeJS Backend and it is working fine on VS Code Live Server on Port 8080 using http://localhost:8080. Now I am serving the website to Shared Hosting with Jupiter cPanel. Uploaded build version of front-end on public_html is working fine but the connectivity with backend is not establishing. I have installed Node.js to hosting and the backend server is running on "mydomain.com/backend".

These are my server codes :

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const authRouter = require('./routes/authRouter');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const categoryRouter = require('./routes/categoryRouter');
const productRouter = require('./routes/productRouter');

// const resourceRouter = require('./routes/resourceRouter');
const paymentRouter = require('./routes/paymentRouter');
const subCategoryRouter = require('./routes/subCategoryRouter');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//configuring env
dotenv.config();//since env file is in root directory no need to add path of the file

//configure database
connectDB();//call to establish connection with database

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));//used in development phase to check the api calls being made

app.listen(PORT);
app.use(cookieParser());

//all routes
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/category', categoryRouter);
app.use('/subCategory', subCategoryRouter);
app.use('/product', productRouter);
// app.use('/resource', resourceRouter);
app.use('/payment', paymentRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json("HELLO universe");
})

console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

And calling the API like this in front-end :

```
const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/auth/login`, { email, password });
```

Inside the .env in front-end :

```
REACT_APP_API = http://example.com/backend
```

My main doubt is what should I use on port value in server.js file and in front-end the backend URL to make connectivity between them???

```
app.listen(PORT);
```

Please help as I am finding the solution from last 4 days.